# How to Elaborate Rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, functional-programming

I would like to transform the below pandas dataframe:

```
dd = pd.DataFrame({ "zz":[1,3], "y": ["a","b"], "x": [[1,2],[1]]})

       x    y   z
0   [1, 2]  a   1
1   [1] b   3
```

into :

```
           x    y   z
    0   1       a   1
    1   1       b   3
    2   2       a   1
```

As you can see, the first row is elaborated in columns X into its individual elements while repeating the other columns y, z. Can I do this without using a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#get lengths of lists
l = dd['x'].str.len()

df = dd.loc[dd.index.repeat(l)].assign(x=np.concatenate(dd['x'])).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   x  y  zz
0  1  a   1
1  2  a   1
2  1  b   3
```

But if order is important:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dd['x'].values.tolist()) 
                          .stack()
                          .sort_index(level=[1,0])
                          .reset_index(name='x')
print (df1)
   level_0  level_1    x
0        0        0  1.0
1        1        0  1.0
2        0        1  2.0

df = df1.join(dd.drop('x',1), on='level_0').drop(['level_0','level_1'], 1)
print (df)
     x  y  zz
0  1.0  a   1
1  1.0  b   3
2  2.0  a   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `join` and `stack` you can

```
In [655]: dd.drop('x', 1).join(
             dd.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.x), axis=1)
               .stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).to_frame('x'))
Out[655]:
   y  z    x
0  a  1  1.0
0  a  1  2.0
1  b  3  1.0
```

Details

```
In [656]: dd.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.x), axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
Out[656]:
0    1.0
0    2.0
1    1.0
dtype: float64

In [657]: dd
Out[657]:
        x  y  z
0  [1, 2]  a  1
1     [1]  b  3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_dd = pd.DataFrame(dd.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['x']),axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True))

new_dd.columns = ['x']

new_dd.merge(dd[['y','zz']], left_index=True, right_index=True)
```